# How to catch exception defined in imported module

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception

to reproduce the issue, open a calc file with below shell command

```
me@konsoles$ soffice --calc --accept="socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager"
```

run python in different console and enter following commands

```
me@konsoles$ python

Python 3.7.5 (default, Feb 23 2021, 13:22:40) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import uno
>>> local_context = uno.getComponentContext()                                                                             
>>> resolver = local_context.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", local_context)
>>> ctx = resolver.resolve("uno:socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext")
>>> smgr = ctx.ServiceManager                                                  
>>> desktop = smgr.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", ctx)
>>> file_handle = desktop.getCurrentComponent()
>>> print("connected to", file_handle.getTitle())
connected to Untitled 1
```

So you can see the file_handle is connected to the uno object.
I just want to verify no wrong sheet is enetered as parameter to the method getByName; if you do give wrong sheet name, a NoSuchElementException is raised

```
>>> test = file_handle.getSheets().getByName("kanoedel")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
__main__.NoSuchElementException
```

so you woudl assume a try except woudl catch it, but it is not defined and it throws it but doesn't catch it, huh!?

```
>>> try:
...     test = file_handle.getSheets().getByName("kanoedel")
... except NoSuchElementException:
...     print("GD")
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
__main__.NoSuchElementException

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
NameError: name 'NoSuchElementException' is not defined
```

With main question, How do I catch that exception?

Comment: Could you share the code where NoSuchElementException is first created?

Comment: I don't think you can catch that exception, it's raised in the [C code](https://docs.libreoffice.org/pyuno/html/pyuno_8cxx_source.html).

Comment: i have looked in vein where this eception is defined, but I cannot ind the module, probably the import uno statement imports it implicitly

Comment: can someone show me then how to mock this 'not catchable' exception out? I am completely lost

Answer (score 0):

I think that in order to catch that exception you need to also import it from the module where it is created.